# Inserting 400 numbers in a text file

Tags: c, file, text, fputs

I am trying to write numbers from 1, up to 400 in a text file. I am using the code below, which is running without any errors, but the file is being left empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *filePointer;
    filePointer = fopen("file.txt","w");
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i > 400; i++)
    {
        fputs("%d, ",i,filePointer);
    }
    fclose(filePointer);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Just a comment on style: `return` is not a function, don't use it like one.

Comment: Please report compiler warnings if you got any. In fact, learn to not ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `fputs` syntax seem wrong. I think it is:

```
int fputs(const char *str, FILE *stream)
```

Pick **@unwind's** approach (as mentioned above) but if you still want to use `fputs` then your fputs line should be expanded into 3 lines:

```
char temp[4];                // String to store 3-digit number + '\0'
sprintf(temp, "%d, ", i);    // Prepare a string for a given number
fputs(temp, filePointer);    // Write the string to the file
```

This should work. #happycoding :)

**PS**: You seem to be following a bit C++ standard in declaring a variable *anywhere*. It is **not** *pure* C. #justsaying

Comment: C has allowed variables to be declared anywhere ever since C99, so you're about 16 years behind the times in your last statement. ;-)

Comment: And when `i` is a two digit/three digit number, you have a buffer overflow.

Comment: @dritech: why is this the accepted answer? It has a buffer overflow and other errors. unwind's answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @PaulR: Totally agreed on the C99. I am kinda old-age purist. I still like to use the K&R approach. :)

Comment: @CoolGuy & Paul R (again): This was not meant to be a **perfect** solution. I just gave him an approach and not the code. In fact, I can find so many more mistakes in my solution than just buffer overflow & 2/3 digit number issues. Also, I did mention, please pick unwind's approach as that is better.

Answer (score 11):

No, there's no way that compiled without some serious-sounding warnings at least.

You're using `fputs()` as if it were `fprintf()`, passing it an integer instead of a `FILE` pointer (which the compiler should not allow) and an extra argument (which the compiler should not allow).

Also your `for` loop is broken. The middle part is an expression that should *be true for as long as the loop should run*, not the other way around.

You meant:

```
for(i = 0; i < 400; ++i)
{
  fprintf(filePointer, "%d, ", i);
}
```

Also, you should check that the file really did open before assuming it did. I/O can fail.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the fputs() usage, the problem is:

`for(i=0; i > 400; i++)`

If you initialize a variable with zero and perform a loop as long as it's greater than 400, that won't last too long.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I fixed the for loop. So what is the method used to write the numbers in a text file? Is there another function which is used instead of the fputs?

Comment: well, look at unwind's answer. That's all you need.